# How to manage URLs and pages to be loaded so fast?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, loading

I noticed that many websites are using some techniques that make pages load so fast, I was thinking that they are using jQuery/Ajax to change URLs and call contents. But I don't understand how they manage URLs and Ajax in the same time ?

For example the website : poki.com, when you click on a game or navigate throw categories it looks like the page is not refreshing and page are quickly loaded, (that was with Ajax ?). Now the question is, when we open a page with the URL of a game or refreshing it, the page is opening without calling Ajax.

How do you think they are managing the tow concept together ? :

1. Creating URLs with JQuery, load content with Ajax.
2. Redirecting links to the exact page created with JS.

Is there a tuto or a code in github that help donging somthing like that ?

Comment: Have a look at the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page OR https://gomakethings.com/how-to-update-a-url-without-reloading-the-page-using-vanilla-javascript/ OR https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-modify-url-without-reloading-the-page-using-javascript/

Comment: See also: https://blog.poki.com/rebuilding-a-web-platform-for-30m-users-90467b0b8293 Since 2017, poki.com appears to be using React / Redux and Go.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a reflexion :

Yes, Ajax (asynchronously) could upgrade speed, but I'am not sure Ajax is the speed solution used by poki.com.

I think a good strategy of caching is preferable (server-side caching, cache nginx,...).

And in PHP, using the flushing is also interresting with heavy pages.

*_Teddy_*